# why is "noclobber" appearing in bash command arguments

Tags: bash, alias

There are a bunch of folders in ~/path/ with names that begin with prefix, and I need to access them very frequently. I'm trying to create a shortcut in .bashrc that will make "prefix example" run the command "cd ~/path/prefixexample".

I encountered the same issue with both functions and aliases:

```
function prefix(){ "cd ~/path/prefix$1"; }

alias prefix="cd ~/path/prefix$1"
```

When I type "prefix 4" (the folder path/prefix4 does exist), I get:

```
bash: cd: path/prefixnoclobber: No such file or directory
```

I don't have admin privileges on this machine, so I can't change some things.

.bashrc already contains a bunch of stuff, but the only relevant thing seems to be "set noclobber". I'm pretty sure replacing arguments with the string "noclobber" is not part of the functionality of the noclobber switch, and commenting this switch out had no effect.

Comment: And what happens if you use a number that does exist?

Comment: Why not just `function prefix(){ cd ~/path/prefix$1; }` ?

Comment: ire - maybe there's a misunderstanding. prefix4 does exist. prefix5 does not exist, and "prefix 5" causes the same error.

Comment: earl - I added the quotes in a haphazard attempt to address possible causes of the error. They don't make a difference.

Comment: quotes do matter - this will never work: `function prefix(){ "cd ~/path/prefix$1"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$1` in the alias command is being replaced with whatever the first argument to the setup script happens to be (apparently, "noclobber"), rather than the argument to the alias/function. You need to do two things:

1. Get rid of the alias. Aliases aren't flexible enough to do what you want, but an alias *will* override anything else with the same name (and hence interfere with a better solution).
2. Use a function:

   ```
   prefix() { cd ~/path/prefix"$1"; }
   ```